# FuelPHP can't setup database to work

Tags: php, database, fuelphp

I'm using FuelPHP and I can't set up my database so it would work. I know that i'm using right information but i'm not sure if I put it in right place.

```
<?php

return array(
'default' => array(
    'connection'  => array(
        'dsn'        => 'mysql:host=modernt@moderntalking.lt;dbname=modernt',
        'username'   => 'modernt',
        'password'   => 'pass',
    ),
),
);
```

This is my db.php in APP/config/db.php

Comment: Are you sure, you should use `modernt` host and not `localhost`?

Comment: I'm testing it not on local machine. I'm doing it on the server

Answer (score 2):

Environment configurations are merged, and the environment wins.

So if you have ./app/config/db.php containing `return array('a');` and you'll have ./app/config/development/db.php containing `return array('b');`, then after reading your config, you'll end up with "b".

So if you use environment based config (like DB does by default), only add configuration to the global file that is truely global, otherwise it gets overwritten in the merge.

Answer (score 0):

Check this

```
'dsn' => 'mysql:host=moderntalking.lt;dbname=modernt',
```

Comment: i still get the same error :
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Fuel\Core\FuelException' with message 'Unable to create or write to the log file. Please check the permissions on /home/modernt/domains/moderntalking.lt/public_html/fuel/app/logs/.

Comment: Did you check the permissions?

Answer (score 0):

```
// a MySQL driver configuration
'development' => array(
    'type'           => 'mysqli',
    'connection'     => array(
        'hostname'       => 'localhost',
        'port'           => '3306',
        'database'       => 'fuel_db',
        'username'       => 'your_username',
        'password'       => 'y0uR_p@ssW0rd',
        'persistent'     => false,
        'compress'       => false,
    ),
    'identifier'     => '`',
    'table_prefix'   => '',
    'charset'        => 'utf8',
    'enable_cache'   => true,
    'profiling'      => false,
    'readonly'       => false,
),

// a PDO driver configuration, using PostgreSQL
'production' => array(
    'type'           => 'pdo',
    'connection'     => array(
        'dsn'            => 'pgsql:host=localhost;dbname=fuel_db',
        'username'       => 'your_username',
        'password'       => 'y0uR_p@ssW0rd',
        'persistent'     => false,
        'compress'       => false,
    ),
    'identifier'     => '"',
    'table_prefix'   => '',
    'charset'        => 'utf8',
    'enable_cache'   => true,
    'profiling'      => false,
    'readonly'       => array('slave1', 'slave2', 'slave3'),
),

'slave1' => array(
    // configuration of the first production readonly slave db
),

'slave2' => array(
    // configuration of the second production readonly slave db
),

'slave3' => array(
    // configuration of the third production readonly slave db
),
```

Basic procedure of setup FuelPHP..may be its help you .Thank you

Comment: well i read that tutorial in framework page a lot of times, but it doesn't work.
just to be sure, where to put this piece of code? now it sits in App/config/development/db.php

Comment: @Casad link is http://fuelphp.com/docs/classes/database/introduction.html   . I flow this this and its work for that reason i share this with you .

Comment: well i saw that, and it's not working, that's why i'm asking what's wrong

Answer (score 0):

First, check your environment configuration in `app/bootstrap.php`:

```
/**
* Your environment. Can be set to any of the following:
*
* Fuel::DEVELOPMENT
* Fuel::TEST
* Fuel::STAGING
* Fuel::PRODUCTION
*/
Fuel::$env = (isset($_SERVER['FUEL_ENV']) ? $_SERVER['FUEL_ENV'] : Fuel::DEVELOPMENT);
```

Then modify the db.php file accordingly (`app/development/db.php, app/production/db.php, app/staging/db.php, app/test/db.php`)